# How to Sum, Filtered Rows based on drop down selection in Excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet(Data) having columns Name, Region, Payment Type and Amount. I created a 'Data Validation' drop down list of Regions in another sheet(Output). When I select a particular Region from the drop down list, total Amount for that Region should be displayed in the next cell. I wrote a VBA code for this, but the cell doesn't display the total amount when I select the Region from the list. Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Here is the Images
[[Data and Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTFYd.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wZ74.png)

Here is the VBA code which I tried.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rngRegion As Range
    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim selectedRegion As String
    Dim totalAmount As Double
    Dim outputCell As Range
    
    ' Define the range for the region dropdown list in Sheet2
    Set rngRegion = Sheets("Output").Range("A1:B2") ' Modify the range as needed
    
    ' Define the range for the data in Sheet1
    Set rngData = Sheets("Data").Range("A2:D300") ' Modify the range as needed
    
    ' Define the output cell for total amount in Sheet2
    Set outputCell = Sheets("Output").Range("B2") ' Modify the cell as needed
    
    ' Check if the changed cell is within the region dropdown list in Sheet2
    If Not Intersect(Target, rngRegion) Is Nothing Then
        ' Get the selected region
        selectedRegion = Target.Value
        
        ' Reset total amount
        totalAmount = 0
        
        ' Loop through each row in the data range in Sheet1
        For Each cell In rngData
            ' Check if the region matches the selected region
            If cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = selectedRegion Then
                ' Add the amount to the total
                totalAmount = totalAmount + cell.Offset(0, 3).Value
            End If
        Next cell
        
        ' Display the total amount in the output cell in Sheet2
        outputCell.Value = totalAmount
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not simply use a `SUMIF`-formula? `=SUMIF(Data!B:B,B2,Data!D:D)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your present code recursively call your sub because when you set the result to the cell it again invokes the sub.

Two ways to correct the issue

1. Define only the dropdown as the rngRegion

```
Set rngRegion = Sheets("Output").Range("A2") ' Modify the range as needed
```

2. Apply the EnableEvents property like this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rngRegion As Range
    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim selectedRegion As String
    Dim totalAmount As Double
    Dim outputCell As Range
    
    ' Define the range for the region dropdown list in Sheet2
    Set rngRegion = Sheets("Output").Range("A1:B2") ' Modify the range as needed
    
    ' Define the range for the data in Sheet1
    Set rngData = Sheets("Data").Range("A2:D300") ' Modify the range as needed
    
    ' Define the output cell for total amount in Sheet2
    Set outputCell = Sheets("Output").Range("B2") ' Modify the cell as needed

    Application.EnableEvents = False    'added
    
    ' Check if the changed cell is within the region dropdown list in Sheet2
    If Not Intersect(Target, rngRegion) Is Nothing Then
        ' Get the selected region
        selectedRegion = Target.Value
        
        ' Reset total amount
        totalAmount = 0
        
        ' Loop through each row in the data range in Sheet1
        For Each cell In rngData
            ' Check if the region matches the selected region
            If cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = selectedRegion Then
                ' Add the amount to the total
                totalAmount = totalAmount + cell.Offset(0, 3).Value
            End If
        Next cell
        
        ' Display the total amount in the output cell in Sheet2
        outputCell.Value = totalAmount
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True   'added
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Black cat, for your valuable piece of code. Now the program working fantastic. You are Super! Cheers and Best Regards...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine, I just updated the cells in the code.

Try changing the below lines in your code (***Assuming your dropdown is in cell A2 and you want to output sum in cell B2***):

*Set rngRegion = Sheets("Output").Range("A1:B2")*

--->
*Set rngRegion = Sheets("Output").Range("A2:A2")*

Answer (score 0):

### A Worksheet Change: Sum If

- If you think about it more deeply, the idea is flawed. You should additionally create a code for the other sheet, monitor the changes in columns 2 and 4, and write the result accordingly (remember the worksheet change event works with changed values, not formulas). But let's continue with your idea and see why.
- After taking care of the 'immediate' issues, when you select the region in `A2`, `B2` will correctly show the sum of amounts by the selected region.
- Now when you add (modify) data in the source sheet and **return to the target sheet**, the sum in `B2` is still the same and could be incorrect (busted!) as long as you don't select another region.
- So I've added the worksheet activate event to cover for this.
- But now, when you add (modify) data in the source sheet and **don't return to the target sheet**, you have to realize that the sum in `B2` might be incorrect (busted!) as long as you don't activate the target sheet.
- If the number in `B2` only serves the purpose of showing the current sum by region, this will do. If not i.e. you want to perform calculations with this cell's value, you better handle this properly as described at the beginning.

**Your Idea Improved in the `Sheet2` Module (`"Output"`)**

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    UpdateSum
End Sub
```

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    UpdateSum Target
End Sub
```

```vb
Private Sub UpdateSum(Optional ByVal Target As Variant)

    Const SRC_SHEET_NAME As String = "Data"
    Const SRC_LOOKUP_COLUMN As Long = 2
    Const SRC_RETURN_COLUMN As Long = 4
    
    Const TGT_LOOKUP_CELL As String = "A2"
    Const TGT_RETURN_CELL As String = "B2"
    Const TGT_NO_DATA_IN_SOURCE As String = "No data!"
    
    Dim tws As Worksheet: Set tws = Me
    
    Dim tcell As Range
    
    If IsMissing(Target) Then
        Set tcell = tws.Range(TGT_LOOKUP_CELL)
    Else
        Set tcell = Intersect(tws.Range(TGT_LOOKUP_CELL), Target)
        If tcell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim SearchString As String: SearchString = CStr(tcell.Value)
    Set tcell = tws.Range(TGT_RETURN_CELL)
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = tws.Parent.Sheets(SRC_SHEET_NAME)
    
    Dim srg As Range, srCount As Long
    
    With sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        srCount = .Rows.Count - 1
        If srCount > 0 Then Set srg = .Resize(srCount).Offset(1)
    End With
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        
    If srg Is Nothing Then
        tcell.Value = TGT_NO_DATA_IN_SOURCE
    Else
        tcell.Value = sws.Evaluate("SUMIF(" _
            & srg.Columns(SRC_LOOKUP_COLUMN).Address & ",""" & SearchString _
            & """," & srg.Columns(SRC_RETURN_COLUMN).Address & ")")
    End If
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```